# No veo el componente SerialPort en VisualStudio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, arduino

Estoy tratando de controlar un motor conectado a mi computador por USB con arduino pero no veo el componente SerialPort en mi version de VisualStudio (2022).

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GabhVrNhVRY&t=1359s&ab_channel=EducationisLife)

Y asi se ve mi IDE, deberia estar donde apunta la flecha

[image: Deberia estar donde apunta la flecha]

Comment: Cuando inicializaste el proyecto, ¿seleccionaste [`.NET Framework`](https://ibb.co/DzpSbXb)? El serial port está disponible solo en `.NET Framework`.

Comment: Si, lo seleccione porque es el que uso usualmente para trabajar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Puedes crear el componente directamente desde el código del formulario?

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
port.Open()
```

De todas formas, en las últimas versiones del Framework o Core, no está añadido por defecto, es posible que lo tengas que descargar de .nuget antes de poder utilizarlo:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/

Hace años que no utilizo Windows Forms, pero no muestra inicialmente todos los componentes que tienes en tu sistema, existía una opción para añadir componentes que te permitía ajustar los elementos que aparecen en el cuadro de herramientas.